# Join tables only if the first join yields no results

Tags: sql, join, db2

I have 5 tables A, B, C, D, E.

The primary key of A is a foreign key in B, C, D, E. They don't have their own primary key.

I have to implement a certain logic where

```
if ("A JOIN B JOIN C" IS NOT NULL)
    return result of "A JOIN B JOIN C"
else if ("A JOIN C" IS NOT NULL)
    return result of "A JOIN C"
else if ("A JOIN D" IS NOT NULL)
    return result of "A JOIN D"
else if ("A JOIN E" IS NOT NULL)
    return result of "A JOIN E"
else return A

where A.primarykey = <some value>
```

I have to implement this in a single sql and not a stored proc.
I can't think of a way to achieve this. I use DB2.
I would really appreciate if you could give some directions on how to proceed.

Comment: Do LEFT JOINs'.

Comment: It's not very helpful to give invalid code to try to describe something rather than making the effort to way what you actually mean. It doesn't mean anything so conveys only a vagueness to guess from. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Such a parmeterized statement can be mostly mechanically translated to SQL. PS Read about how EAV is usually an anti-pattern.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. You may edit input data to check the result.

```
WITH 
  A (ID, AV) AS (VALUES (1, 'A1'))
, B (ID, BV) AS (VALUES 
(1, 'B1'), (1, 'B2')
--(2, 'B1'), (2, 'B2')
) , C (ID, CV) AS (VALUES 
(1, 'C1'), (1, 'C2'), (1, 'C3')
--(2, 'C1'), (2, 'C2'), (2, 'C3')
), D (ID, DV) AS (VALUES 
(1, 'D1'), (1, 'D2')
--(2, 'D1'), (2, 'D2')
) , E (ID, EV) AS (VALUES 
(1, 'E1'), (1, 'E2'), (1, 'E3')
--(2, 'E1'), (2, 'E2'), (2, 'E3')
)
SELECT A.ID, A.AV, B.BV, C.CV, C1.CV AS CV1, D.DV, E.EV
, 
CASE
  WHEN B.ID  IS NOT NULL THEN 'A+B+C'
  WHEN C1.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'A+C'
  WHEN D.ID  IS NOT NULL THEN 'A+D'
  WHEN E.ID  IS NOT NULL THEN 'A+E'
  ELSE 'A'
END JOIN_PATH
FROM A
LEFT JOIN 
(
B 
JOIN C ON C.ID=B.ID
)              ON B.ID  = A.ID 
LEFT JOIN C C1 ON C1.ID = A.ID AND B.ID IS NULL
LEFT JOIN D    ON D.ID  = A.ID AND B.ID IS NULL AND C1.ID IS NULL 
LEFT JOIN E    ON E.ID  = A.ID AND B.ID IS NULL AND C1.ID IS NULL AND D.ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
select
  case 
     when B.key is not null and C.key is not null then 'A+B+C'
     when C.key is not null then 'A+C'
     when D.key is not null then 'A+D'
     when E.key is not null then 'A+E'
  end
from A
left join B on B.key = A.key
left join C on C.key = A.key
left join D on D.key = A.key
left join E on E.key = A.key
left join F on F.key = A.key
```

The `case` statement will stop evaluating further as soon as a `when` condition is met, so effectively you've got an `if-else if` block.

I am just returning string values in the example, but you could return field values as well, depending on your needs, eg:

```
  case 
     when B.key is not null and C.key is not null then b.f1
     when C.key is not null then c.f1
     when D.key is not null then d.f1
     when E.key is not null then e.f1
  end as 'f1'
  ,
  case 
     when B.key is not null and C.key is not null then b.f2
     when C.key is not null then c.f2
     when D.key is not null then d.f2
     when E.key is not null then e.f2
  end as 'f2'
```

Comment: You can't just left join tables without additional conditions. For example, if you have B rows in `B`, C rows in `C`, D rows in `D`, E rows in `E` with the same key, this query returns Cartesian product of all these rows in all tables for this key, which is unlikely desired.

Comment: I understand the answer, but not the upvote.  This ignores all the "else" conditions in the question and just brings all the tables together.

Answer (score 1):

You want `LEFT JOIN`s with with some additional logic to handle the "else" part of what you are doing:

```
select . . .
from A left join
     B 
     on B.key = A.key left join
     C
     on C.key = A.key left join
     C c2
     on c2.key = A.key and
        c.key is null left join  -- first attempt failed
     D
     on D.key = A.key and
        c.key is null and
        c2.key is null left join  -- earlier joins failed
     E
     on e.key = A.key and
        c.key is null and
        c2.key is null and
        d.key is null
```

Comment: Your statement returns empty result set, if `A JOIN B` is empty.

Comment: Now If A JOIN B is empty, but A JOIN C is not, then you get the result for A JOIN B JOIN C. But A JOIN B JOIN C is empty because of empty A JOIN B.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein . . . This should keep all rows in `A` when there are no matches in `B` or `C`, so the subsequent `join`s should match.